# How best to do routing to a specific screen? iOS, MVC

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, push-notification, deep-linking

There is a task when the user clicks on the deep link (or push notification), then open the corresponding application screen. The project is written in MVC, how best to do routing to a specific screen? Please tell me or show examples of the correct architecture.